# Find coordinates of bisector of two lines with only coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates

so i got 90% of the code working i just need a hand with this last bit. I need to figure out how to get the coordinates of the intersection of two lines where i only have the cordinates of both lines. I dont have to worry about the lines not crossing cause that isn't how it is setup.

```py
import math , random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def build_curve(start_x, start_y, control_x, control_y, end_x, end_y, resolution, color):
  
  control_line_cords_x = []
  control_line_cords_y = []
  guide_line_cords_x = []
  guide_line_cords_y = []
  
  for cycle in range(0,resolution):
    guide_line_cords_x.append(start_x + ((control_x - start_x)/resolution) * cycle)
    guide_line_cords_y.append(start_y + ((control_y - start_y)/resolution) * cycle)

    control_line_cords_x.append(control_x + ((end_x - control_x)/resolution) * cycle)
    control_line_cords_y.append(control_y + ((end_y - control_y)/resolution) * cycle)

  for loop in range(0,len(control_line_cords_x)):
    plt.plot([guide_line_cords_x[loop],control_line_cords_x[loop]],[guide_line_cords_y[loop],control_line_cords_y[loop]], color = color)
  plt.plot([start_x,control_x,end_x],[start_y,control_y,end_y], color = color)
  plt.title('Bezier Curve')
  plt.show()
```

This is the code i got so far but i need to know the coordinates of the intersections so i can plot the curve separately. I simplified the problem down to this :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SPEu.png)

Comment: Did you search for `how to get the coordinates of the intersection of two lines`? Which part are you having trouble with? the math? Plotting the point? Interpolation? You really haven't asked a question. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: @wwii im having problem with the maths as the plotting works just fine but i dont know how to generate a coordinates that define the curve